# Calculated Heikin Ashi values different from interface

Tags: pine-script

I'm using Heikin Ashi values to plot an indicator on a candles chart using

```
src=security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
```

It works. Chart is rendered correctly. But the values are slightly different from what I get if I use

```
src=close
```

and change chart type to "Heikin Ashi" in Trading View.
What could create this discrepancy?
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this source, it gives exactly the same values as the built-in Heikin-Ashi charts.
https://www.tradingview.com/script/U1QGgSOw-Heikin-Ashi-Source-Function-HTF/